# UIImage size limitations and the new iPad retina display

Tags: ipad, ios5, uiimage, new-operator, retina-display

The Apple developer docs advise to keep UIImages to be 1024x1024 at most, but does this change with the new iPad?

In other words can we create UIImages at the size of 2048x1536 (only on new iPad), or do we need to still work around within the 1024 pixel limit?

I heard that the new iPad has double the RAM as the original iPad, so maybe this is possible?

I don't have a new iPad to test with, so I'm wondering if anyone has any insight.

Comment: I submitted an update for my app to the App Store that uses larger UIImages (max 2048x2048) for the new iPad and I think this seems to be ok. 

I profiled memory usage using Instruments and actually did not see any signs of excessive memory gobbling using the larger UIImage sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer looks to be yes, the new iPad (and probably the iPad 2) supports UIImages larger than the recommended 1024x1024 size mentioned in the Apple developer docs.

If you do use large UIImages, though, be sure to monitor your memory usage using Instruments (Memory -> Allocations -> Live Bytes).